# How to place two check boxes at the same row in Vaadin CRUD?

Tags: java, vaadin, crud, vaadin14

I have an `entity` that has these two fields.

```
private boolean alarmActive;
private boolean messageHasBeenSent;
```

And when I show this with Vaadin CRUD API.

```
GridCrud<Alarm> alarmCrud = new GridCrud<>(Alarm.class);
CrudFormFactory<Alarm> crudFormFactory = new DefaultCrudFormFactory<Alarm>(Alarm.class);
alarmCrud.setCrudFormFactory(crudFormFactory);
alarmCrud.getGrid().setColumns("name", "email", "message", "alarmActive", "messageHasBeenSent", "sa0Min", "sa0Max", "sa1Min", "sa1Max", "sa1dMin", "sa1dMax", "sa2dMin", "sa2dMax", "sa3dMin", "sa3dMax", "a0Min", "a0Max", "a1Min", "a1Max", "a2Min", "a2Max", "a3Min", "a3Max");
alarmCrud.getGrid().setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
crudFormFactory.setUseBeanValidation(true);
crudFormFactory.setVisibleProperties(new String[] { "name", "email", "message", "alarmActive", "messageHasBeenSent", "sa0Min", "sa0Max", "sa1Min", "sa1Max", "sa1dMin", "sa1dMax", "sa2dMin", "sa2dMax", "sa3dMin", "sa3dMax", "a0Min", "a0Max", "a1Min", "a1Max", "a2Min", "a2Max", "a3Min", "a3Max" });
```

I get this view when I try to add a new row in the CRUD database.

[image]

**Question:**

I want to have both check boxes on the same row? How can I do that with this current entity?

I know there is a way to have multiple check boxes at the same row, but that method is not the correct because it depends each checkbox need to become an entity and that entity is not connected to my database CRUD entity.

In this example below, he have used

```
@ManyToMany
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@NotNull
private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();
```

To create multiple check boxes at one row. The problem is that the entity `Group` is distinct from entity `User` if they begins with empty.

Here he loads the `groupService` into a check box provider and this creates multiple check boxes on the same row.

```
crud.getCrudFormFactory().setFieldProvider("groups", new CheckBoxGroupProvider<>("Groups", groupService.findAll(), Group::getName));
```

https://github.com/alejandro-du/crudui/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/org/vaadin/crudui/demo/ui/view/SimpleCrudView.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I done it adding a component as column.

To do that, you need to remove from

```
alarmCrud.getGrid().setColumns(...)
```

the columns you want to group, and add them instead in a [HorizontalLayout rendererd as column](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/using-components). Into HorizontalLayout you can add CheckBox, binding manually the values.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is a better solution, but one workaround is to add a line break after your `Message` field using JavaScript. This should have the effect of making both checkboxes in the same row.

To do this, you'd need to add an editor-opened listener in which you execute the following code to add the line break

```
com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.getCurrent().getPage()
        .executeJs("formLayout = document.getElementsByTagName('vaadin-form-layout')[0];"
                + "var br = document.createElement('br');"
                + "formLayout.insertBefore(br, formLayout.children[3]);");
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to use JavaScript with Vaadin. It's creates a messy code. ;) If it's not possible to have the checkboxes at the same row with this shape of entity, then I have to accept that it's not possible.

Comment: Understandable. You might want to ask the question also on this addon's page: https://vaadin.com/directory/component/crud-ui-add-on/discussions. Perhaps someone there would have a better idea.